Getting PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type even when there is no data type mismatch
I was writing a function which has a select statement.
SELECT
    t_vf_dashboard_pie_chart_tbl(
        emp_id,
        total_collected_amount,
        due_amount,
        config_id,
        colltext,
        duetext,
        payment_date,
        seq,
        dpd
    ) BULK COLLECT INTO v_ret
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            x_login_id emp_id,
            SUM(nvl(paid_amount, '0')) total_collected_amount,
            SUM(nvl(due_amount, 0)) due_amount,
            1 AS config_id,
            'collection' colltext,
            'Due' duetext,
            payment_date,
            seq,
            'DPD (>90)'      AS dpd
        FROM
            tb_dashboard_pie_chart_vf_final
        GROUP BY
            seq,
            payment_date -- order by seq,PAYMENT_DATE
    )

I am getting error - PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type.
The function is returning t_vf_dashboard_pie_chart while declaring and at the very last of the function I am returning v_ret. In the function v_ret is declared as t_vf_dashboard_pie_chart and t_vf_dashboard_pie_chart is a table of T_VF_DASHBOARD_PIE_CHART as you can see below -
I have declared type as below:
create or replace TYPE "T_VF_DASHBOARD_PIE_CHART" as table of T_VF_DASHBOARD_PIE_CHART_TBL;

create or replace TYPE "T_VF_DASHBOARD_PIE_CHART_TBL" force as object (
    "EMP_ID" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "AMOUNT_COLLECTED" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
    "DUE_AMOUNT" FLOAT, 
    "CONFIG_ID" NUMBER, 
    "COLLTEXT" CHAR(10 BYTE), 
    "DUETEXT" CHAR(3 BYTE), 
    "PAYMENT_DATE" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
    "SEQ" NUMBER, 
    "DPD" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)
      ) ;

Also the table used in this select statement has the following columns and datatypes -
LOAN_NO            VARCHAR2(50)   
DUE_AMOUNT         FLOAT(126)     
DPD                VARCHAR2(50)   
EMP_ID             VARCHAR2(50)   
YEAR_MONTH         VARCHAR2(10)   
PAID_STATUS        VARCHAR2(4000) 
PAID_AMOUNT        VARCHAR2(4000) 
PAYMENT_DATE       VARCHAR2(4000) 
SEQ                NUMBER         
INSERT_DT          TIMESTAMP(6)

I don't see any mismatch but I am still getting this error, can someone help me what I am doing wrong?
I have tried removing the sum() and changing the paid_amount to nvl(paid_amount, '0') so that it matches the varchar, also I tried adding nvl to payment_date column as this was the only column with null value but this also returned the same error.
I am unable to figure out what I am doing wrong? I don't see any mismatch in the data-types of the type declared and the variables returned by the select query, also I am using nested tables so more than one row cannot cause the issue as well, so what can be wrong here. If required I can provide the complete function which I wrote as well.

Your code does not seem to error, so please provide a [mcve] showing it does. Maybe the problem is when you call the function - are you sure you're putting the result of the call into a variable of the right type, for instance?

Why does the collection user-defined data type have no suffix and the object that is in the collection have the _TBL suffix? Semantically, this appears to be the wrong way round.

double check your type names. ensure that the constructor used in the select clause is the object type, not the table type, and the v_ret is of the table type, not the object type.

Getting error here, please check if this helps.

@VaibhavChandak - not really; that is missing a final /. With that fixes ig gets other errors. And your call isn't right - in your real code are you just selecting the value, or calling the function from a PL/SQL block and assigning the result to a variable? I suspect the latter, and that is defined as the wrong type (maybe because of the odd naming...).

@AlexPoole I am trying to call function directly from the SQL Developer to test the code.
